# How do I search values from json using requests?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm trying to get attributes from this JSON file from an API using requests.
This is my code:

```
import requests

print "Enter a user ID or name..."
inp = raw_input()

print "Select a mode..."
mode = raw_input()
def usage():
    print "0 = osu!"
    print "1 = Taiko"
    print "2 = CtB"
    print "3 = osu!mainia"

if mode == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3":   
r=requests.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_useru="+inp+"&k=bd1f7038XXXXXXX+mode)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
print(r.text)
```

Which returns this JSON:

{
    "user_id": "2",
    "username": "peppy",
    "count300": "624689",
    "count100": "110468",
    "count50": "22795",
    "playcount": "6960",
    "ranked_score": "409604138",
    "total_score": "1806143869",
    "pp_rank": "187209",
    "level": "64.9581",
    "pp_raw": "753.665",
    "accuracy": "96.74224853515625",
    "count_rank_ss": "16",
    "count_rank_s": "66",
    "count_rank_a": "109",
    "country": "AU",
    "pp_country_rank": "4363",
    "events": []
}

If I try to do something like this:

print(r.content[username]

I get this error:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\osu_api\osu.py", line 18, in 
    print(r.content[username])
    NameError: name 'username' is not defined

Comment: Did you try `r.content["username"]`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\osu_api\osu.py", line 18, in <module>
        print(r.content ["username"])
    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the json using `json.loads`, and then access the data:

```
import json
data = json.loads(r.content)
print data[0]['username']
```

Comment: I changed the code to: d = json.loads(r.content)
    print d[0]["username"] and it returns the correct data if you edit your post, i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Do you mean you had to add `[0]` as if it was an array?

Comment: Yes, I had to add it or it will give the error described above.